# Recently upgraded android studio version to 3.5.1 but i see log.d or v or w none of them are getting printed

Tags: android

Recently upgraded android studio version to 3.5.1 but i see log.d or v or w none of them are getting printed.
while debugging i noticed is it skips the below line
Log.d("oncreate started")

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Where are you calling these log statements?

Comment: Log statement in activities

Comment: Where in activity? method? `onCreate`?

Comment: yes inside onCreate method

Comment: Works just fine for me.. Can you elaborate more on the issue? Does the activity get invoked? Also, please try to use the log in `onResume`..

Comment: Yes activity is getting invoked when it comes to log.d line its just skips and moves forward